# Managing Zero dates - cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, int

Morning All,

> I need to mange dates greater than 2261 in my file. I'm getting the
>   above error when executing :

```
m = df['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(int) > 2261
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

> Details of column causing error:

```
display(df['maturity_date'].dtypes)
dtype('O')

display(df['maturity_date'].describe())
count                        3709
unique                        781
top       2166-09-23 00:00:00.000
freq                          234
Name: maturity_date, dtype: object

display(df[df['maturity_date'].isnull()])
No records returned

display(df[df['maturity_date']==0]['maturity_date'] )
764     0
931     0
1173    0
Name: maturity_date, dtype: object
```

> Possibly error raised as you cant convert zeros? My intended code to
>   update dates after it works:

```
#Convert dates greater than 2261
display(df['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(int) > 2261)
df['maturity_date'] = df['maturity_date'].mask(m, '2261' +  to df['maturity_date'].str[4:]) # for all dates greater than python max date replace
df['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])
```

Comment: Check a DF with `pd.isnull().values.any()` and if `True` do `df.fillna(0)`

Comment: Well the `dtype` of `maturity_date` makes this a bit fishy. You probably have a column of mixed integers, and strings. `.isnull()` does not work to find the `'NaN'` string, since it is not actually null, but that will cause the error you're seeing when trying to typecast. Try looking for `df[df['maturity_date']=='NaN']`

Comment: When I read the file in I convert all NaN to zero. In this case there are only three records with zero. df.isnull().values.any() = false

Comment: No records are returned from df[df['maturity_date']=='NaN']

Comment: Then I would try `df['test'] = pd.to_numeric(df['maturity_date'].str[:4], errors='coerce')` and then look at `df.loc[df.test.isnull(), 'maturity_date']` which will tell you exactly which values are giving you the issue.

Comment: Looks to be the rows with a 0 for the maturity date.

Comment: 764     0
931     0
1173    0

Comment: all have NaN for Test. So would some sort of if statement be appropriate i.e. where the date is zero just set to 2261 otherwise test the year date value?

Comment: .str[:4].astype(int) appears not to work for 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You need to first convert your integers to strings so you can use the `.str` method.

```
m = df['maturity_date'].astype('str').str[:4].astype(int) > 2261
```

The issue is that if you don't want to call .str on an integer value. When you do, it converts it to `NaN`, which then gives you an issue with converting to an integer.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0, '0', '0000', '000']})

df.value.str[:4]
#0     NaN
#1       0
#2    0000
#3     000
#Name: value, dtype: object

df.value.astype('str').str[:4]
#0       0
#1       0
#2    0000
#3     000
#Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now on the following line:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: df['maturity_date'] = df['maturity_date'].mask(m, '2261' + df['maturity_date'].str[4:])

Comment: @PeterLucas  well yes, you would again need to use `df['maturity_date'].astype('str').str[4:]` in your code above because you never assigned the type casting to string back to maturity date. If you want, perhaps do `df['maturity_date'] = df['maturity_date'].astype('str')` and then you can always just use `.str` after it. Remember, that most operations in pandas return a copy that you need to assign back.

Comment: @PeterLucas Or if you want to solve this a lot earlier, just replace the `NaN` with the `'0'` string instead of the integer zero when you replace in the beginning

Comment: Thanks @ALollz works well. I've got some reading to do on this ; )